# Adding a keyframed Brownian Motion to an object

Tags: python, particles, physics, keyframes, mathematics

How can I give an object a motion like the particles' Brownian motion, keyframing the object location value for each frame?
Is there a better way than just using a random value?

Answer (score 1):

You could add keyframe modifiers.

1. Add keyframe to the x,y,z positionsn at the beginning of the animation
2. Go to the Graph Editor -> right panel (press N to show it) -> "Modifiers" label -> Add Modifier -> Noise.
3. Do the operation 2 to the three keyframes (X, Y and Z positions).
4. In the Modifier panel (where you just added the modifier) of each keyframe (X, Y and Z) modify the noise properties in order to make them different each other and to set the Brownian motion as you want.